# s:iterator test if at certain iteration

Tags: struts2

I have searched around and cannot find an answer.

Say I have a list in session of 5 items in session.  How do I tell if I am at a certain iteration in the loop of s:iterator?  For example say list is `[a,b,c,e,f]` and I want to iterate through list and print a,b,c, then inject/print d, then print e f so on the page it looks like the list is `a b c d e f`.

I have been trying this:

```
<s:iterator value="example" status="stat">
<s:if test="#stat.count == '3'">
    inject d...
</s:if>
<s:else>
    s:property tag to print values
</s:else>
</s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The status attribute you are looking for is "index", not "count". Also, I didn't know if it was a typo in the code or just in your post, but your status="stat" attribute has the equals sign inside the quotes. Try this instead:

```
<s:iterator value="example" status="stat">
<s:if test="#stat.index == '3'">
    inject d...
</s:if>
<s:else>
    s:property tag to print values
</s:else>
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer about index vs count. I used what you mentioned above and also noticed I had to omit the ' around the index number . I am thinking this must be a bug in the version of struts2 I am running since its older. When I did not omit the single quotes it would never evaluate and pass the if test it would always print out the else block.

Comment: It isn't a bug "3" is string, '3' is the char and 3 is the number.